# How to render variables without quotes in bash script?

Tags: bash, quoting, variable

The following script:

```
$ cat runme01.sh 
#!/bin/bash

A=myval
B=$A/{fix}
C=$A/fix

set -xT

echo $B
echo $C
```

prints the following if ran:

```
$ ./runme01.sh 
+ echo 'myval/{fix}'
myval/{fix}
+ echo myval/fix
myval/fix
```

As you see, variable `B` is passed to `echo` in single quotes, while variable `C` is passed w/o them.

Probably curly braces  cause this.

I would like to pass them w/o quotes always. How to do that?

Comment: you're not doing anything at all; `set -x` is apparently adding the quotes, to prevent unintentional brace expansion. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve (by passing variables around)?  (Also, always quote your variables!)

Comment: That's just how `set -x` shows the commands. No quotes are involved (but double quotes should've been involved on your side).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Never try to interpret the trace output as anything other than something purely informational. It's debugging output.

The fact that it shows the braces in single quotes does not mean very much other than that the shell interpreted that particular string as `myval/{fix}` and nothing else. *In particular, it does **not** mean that the string was passed quoted!*  The shell  adds the single quotes in the trace output because braces are *sometimes* special, however, in this case they are not (because you never use an actual brace expansion).

The same happens here (running in an empty directory):

```
$ echo *
+ echo '*'
*
```

There is no quoting of the `*` in my command, so the shell will *try* to expand it.  It does not expand to anything, so it remains unexpanded.  The code that produces the tracing output notices that there is a `*` in a string and quotes it. *It's a mechanical adding of single quotes based on what character are present in the string that is printed by the tracing, it does not affect the command or its outcome in any way whatsoever.*

To illustrate this again:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Jun 14 20:15 "filename"
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Jun 14 20:13 'filename'
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Jun 14 20:14 *
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Jun 14 20:14 **
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Jun 14 20:14 123
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Jun 14 20:14 file
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Jun 14 20:14 long name
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Jun 14 20:14 {}
```

```
$ echo *
+ echo '"filename"' ''\''filename'\''' '*' '**' 123 file 'long name' '{}'
"filename" 'filename' * ** 123 file long name {}
```

I.e., certain characters in a string will cause the code that produces the tracing output to add quotes around that string in `bash`.  The shell also escapes single quotes in strings.

Compare this with `dash` or `pdksh`:

```
$ echo *
+ echo "filename" 'filename' * ** 123 file long name {}
"filename" 'filename' * ** 123 file long name {}
```

These particular shells do not add the quotes (or escape single quotes).  It really doesn't matter, it's just debugging output.

---

Always double quote variable expansions, unless you explicitly want the shell to perform word-splitting and filename generation (globbing) on the strings.

Double quoting is not always *needed*, but it's easier to remember to always double quote than to memorize the contexts in which you don't need to.

Your script, corrected:

```
#!/bin/bash

A=myval
B="$A/{fix}"
C="$A/fix"

set -xT

printf '%s\n' "$B"
printf '%s\n' "$C"
```

This will ensure that you will always get the values `$B` and `$C` printed to standard output, regardless of their values.  In your original code, if `$A` had been `*`, using `$B` and `$C` unquoted may have pulled in some matching filenames.

Note that the trace output will still do that quoting of the `myval/{fix}` string with this code. Don't worry, it doesn't mean anything, it's just the shell trying to be helpful with its debugging output.

Related:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)

Answer (score 0):

set `IFS=$'\n'` then no word splitting occurs and you can do everything without quotes.

Could be a security risk but from what I seen it's for api stuff which I wouldn't use bash scripts for anyway.

I had people saying it wouldn't work for x or y, but it did.